# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 4 arguments (5 given)udacity

Tags: python

[image]    enter code here
class Movie() :

```
def __init__(self, movie_title, move_storyline , trailer_youtube):
    self.title = movie_title
    self.storyline = move_storyline
    self.poster_image_url = poster_image_url
    self.trailer_youtube_url = trailer_youtube
```

[image]

whats the erorr here !

Comment: You are passing 4 parameters instead of 3. Just check your __init__ function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve... Also provide a full error traceback.  Pictures do not help when trying to replicate the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write `self.poster_image_url = poster_image_url` but you seem to have forgotten to include `poster_image_url` in your parameters to `__init__`. Add it and the number of arguments and parameters will match correctly.